# Theil-Sen estimation, more than one independent variable

Tags: regression, robust

Is the [Theil-Sen estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theil%E2%80%93Sen_estimator) in robust regression only limited to a two dimensional problem or can you use it for more than one independent variable as well?

Comment: no, it's only limited to two dimensional problems. There are many, much better alternative though and those generalize trivially to higher dimensions (search for robust regression here).

Answer (score 5):

There have been a number of proposals for extending Theil-Sen estimation to multiple regression contexts.

I'll point to a couple:

1)

Zhou, W. and R. Serfling (2007),
Multivariate Spatial U-Quantiles: a Bahadur-Kiefer 
Representation, a Theil-Sen Estimator for Multiple 
Regression, and a Robust Dispersion Estimator,
*Journal of Statistical Planning and Inference*, May

[see here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.78.7797&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

---

2)

Wang, X., X. Dang, H. Peng, and H. Zhang (2009),
The Theil-Sen Estimators in a Multiple Linear Regression Model

[see here](http://www.math.iupui.edu/~hpeng/MTSE_0908.pdf) or [here](http://home.olemiss.edu/~xdang/papers/MTSE.pdf) (different versions)

---

The first is based on extending univariate U-quantiles to multivariate U-quantiles, and the second is based on a multivariate median.